# Is it possible to detect all non standard window properties?

Tags: javascript, browser

That is,  I want to detect all the global properties added by libraries such as `$,` `_,` `Backbone`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only way of doing this that I know about, is unfortunately by storing properties of `window` when it's in its initial state and comparing them to the properties of `window` at the time when you are interested in finding the user-defined ones.

It's a dirty "hack" with awful computational complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>), but I don't think there is other way.

```js
// In the very beginning, before anything modifying window runs
const initialWindowProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);

// Later
window.$ = undefined; // Dummy window property addition

const getUserDefinedWindowProperties = () => {
  const windowProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);
  return windowProperties.filter(
    (property) => !initialWindowProperties.includes(property)
  );
}

console.log(getUserDefinedWindowProperties());
```

```css
/* Output console formatting */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: auto; top: 0; }
```